# Tkinter Polygon's Width not being set to zero even though specified

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to draw a few Polygons using tkinter and so I tried the following code:

```py
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=200)
w.pack()

points = [0, 0, 200, 100, 0, 200]
w.create_polygon(points, outline="green",fill='yellow', width=0)

mainloop()
```

and I get the following output

[image]

But the problem is... the width isn't being set to 0. Is this is an internal issue with Tkinter or is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We don't need all the code, but we do need to see more than what you've posted. Just because you're passing `width=0` to `Rectangle` doesn't necessarily mean you are using the `width` correctly when drawing the rectangle.

Comment: Well yes, I thought about that, obviously it isn't practical for anyone to go through lines of code - but the error could be anywhere in the class. Nonetheless I will update the question :)

Comment: I can't imagine it taking more than a dozen or two lines of code to draw your rectangle.  The example needs to be as few lines as possible to illustrate how you're drawing the rectangle.

Comment: I have added one in the example. But the problem is, there is a lot more code to set the options of the Rectangle and it all passes through multiple classes, etc. But I've simplified it to just the bare minimum.

Comment: Alright, so I got rid of all of the code from my library and put everything just in terms of Tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying a color for an outline, so the canvas must draw an outline that is at least one pixel wide in order to show the outline. If you don't want an outline, set `outline` to `None` or the empty string.

Comment: Hmmm... then why does it work properly with rectangles? if I do the same thing and just replace create_polygon with create_rectangle and change the points... it doesn't draw and outline. But Thanks!